# Cygwin Screen and SSH: Utmp slot not found -> not removed

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, cygwin

When I use `screen` on my computer and detach, I am taken back to the command prompt and everything is fine. However, if I SSH into my computer remotely and use screen, when I try to detach I get the error `Utmp slot not found -> not removed`.

It then hangs and I cannot even `ctrl-c`, `ctrl-d` and have to close the Cygwin window. Why is this occuring and how can I fix it?

Note to recreate error by SSH-ing out of your computer then back in:

```
$ screen
(C-a d)
$ ssh -R12345:localhost:22 username@someServer
$ ssh -p12345 username@127.0.0.1
$ screen -r
(C-a d)
```

Comment: You should report this bug to the [Cygwin list](http://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/current/threads.html), cygwin@cygwin.com.

Comment: Ok, will do it now

Answer (score 3):

It looks the culprit is the file `/var/run/utmp`, which in my case is just an empty file, and the only one in the `/var/run/` directory.

For me I just removed it, via `rm /var/run/utmp`,

Or you can rename it, e.g. `mv /var/run/utmp /var/run/utmp~`

Comment: Note that you have to restart `screen` after removing or renaming the file.

Comment: Also note that this file reappeared when I ran the cygwin setup again.

Answer (score 3):

The answer by ryenus did not work for me.  I tried renaming it, removing it, even tried touching /var/run/utmp and chmod'ing it to 0777.  However I did find an answer on another forums that did work.

Simply edit your .screenrc file and add this line:

deflogin off

Comment: Sounds reasonable, upvoted :-)